# Which is preferable form: "we are a human" or "we are human"

Tags: sentence

Which is preferable sentence:

```
We are a human after all.
```

or

```
We are human after all.
```

without `a`

From my perspective both looks the same, or `a` can point on `human` definition

Comment: **We** (plural) cannot be **a** human (unless it's the royal 'we'!). 'Human' is an adjective in the second version.

Comment: Yes. To clarify, if you want to use "human" as a noun, the sentence will have to be "We are humans..." (Not that I ever heard that outside of science fiction though...)

Comment: [Daft Punk](https://youtu.be/PXYeARRyDWk) used "We are human after all." It's literally a song lyric. Now, [Neil Armstrong](https://www.space.com/17307-neil-armstrong-one-small-step-quote.html) maintained he said "That's one small step for **a** man, one giant leap for mankind."

Comment: They mean different things. Without knowing the intended meaning, we can’t tell you definitively.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence **without** an indefinite article uses "human" as an adjective. The sentence **with** an indefinite article uses "human" as a noun. That is the only noticeable difference, and neither is more "preferable" than the other; it all depends on how you want to use the word "human." See [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/human).

(I will note, however, that "We are [no indefinite article] human after all" sounds much more natural and idiomatic.)

Comment: It would be worth noting that the indefinite article in this case should be _plural_, as should the noun _humans_. The article in that case is of course the zero article.

Comment: @oerkelens  Um, how can an indefinite article be plural? I've never heard of *as* or *ans*...

Comment: @oerkelens What you most likely mean to say is that the article should be removed entirely and the sentence should just say, "We are humans after all."

Comment: @oerkelens Articles are always singular, to my understanding.

Comment: "*The article in that case is of course the zero article.*"  oerkelens in a roundabout way is saying  there is no indefinite article when a noun is plural. Which is like "duh", we know! :)

Answer (score 0):

'We' is plural so it would mean the sentence, 'We are human after all' is correct, as well as 'We are humans after all' would also be correct.

If you were to include the 'a' then you could use 'I am a human after all'